# Promise error after updated to Ionic 3.0.1 and Angular 4.0

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

So after I successfully update to Ionic 3.0.1 and Angular 4.0, this error just randomly pop up in the console and I have no idea what is causing this error:

```
core.es5.js:1085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): false
```

I have Firebase and AngularFire in my Ionic project. Not sure if this related to the issue. But it is really frustrated I can not pinpoint the cause of the error. My app still works as normal tho.

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9589

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely caused by loading controller. check out this issue #[9589](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9589)